# Help with series definition, binomial theorem?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, expectation, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

If a stock goes up by a factor $u$ with probability $p$ and down by a factor $d$ with probability $1-p$, find the expected value of the stock after $n$ periods. Assume the periods are independent.

I drew a basic tree diagram for 3 periods just to get a sense of how it works.

I'm having trouble using math to describe the pattern.

Ie. for period $n=3$. letting $X(T)$ be the stock price random variable, I got 
$ E[X]= X(0)[(up)^3+3(up)^2d(l-p)+3upd^2(1-p)^2+d^3(1-p)^3]$

This looks like a binomial expansion, but I'm not sure how to generalize it for n periods. I know it will have n terms in the unsimplified polynomial and a unique 1st and last term.

Please let me know if this is even the right approach!

Comment: It is not clear to me what goes down by a factor $d$ means. Maybe it means that if $d=0.8$ then the stock goes from $100$ to $80$. Or maybe it means that if $d=1.25$ then the stock goes from $100$ to $\frac{100}{1.25}$.

Comment: Just means multiple. Can also be thought of as a percentage. Your first interpretation is correct.

Comment: Is it $X(0)[up+d(1-p)]^n$? Please correct if wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be the initial amount, and let $X_i=u$ with probability $p$, and $X_i=d$ with probability $1-p$. Then the amount after $n$ periods is $W$, where 
$$W=AX_1X_2\cdots X_n.$$
By independence, we have
$$E(W)=AE(X_1)E(X_2)\cdots E(X_n).$$
For any $i$ we have $E(X_i)=pu+(1-p)d$, so $E(W)=A(pu+(1-p)d)^n$.